# How to Change Categories Order in the Admin Dashboard in Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, sorting, categories, admin, dashboard

I have a springboot project.Entities I use are products,product categories,tags and etc.
Admin should be able to custom change the order of categories on the admin dashboard(preferably by using up-down arrow(class is fas fa sort)
Any idea how to achieve that?

I am guessing i should write a function with mapping /order-save but i am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could have a seq_num (sequence number) column in the entity that needs to be able to have the order editable. When the order is changed and the information sent to the backend REST API you could persist the changes with the updated sequence numbers for each item in the list.

When querying for this data you could "order by seq_num" and return the list in the response in the correct order.

Example:

```
   [
      {
          "productId": 1234,
          "productName": "tomato",
          "seqNum": 0
      },
      {
          "productId": 2231,
          "productName": "olive",
          "seqNum": 1
      }
   ]
```